# PHP/MySQL Ad Rotation System

Tags: php, mysql, adrotator

I have decided to do a little ad section on each of my pages but am not exactly sure how it is done. Would the advertiser submit the markup for the ad to me, where  add it o the MySQL DB? Or would they just submit a URL to be iframed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you plan on selling the advertisement placements yourself, you'll be provided with code to insert into your page, often in the form of Javascript.

Comment: you can use opensource for that?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to add anything to the DB, once you registered for any ad campaign, you just have to place the code the advertiser provided where you want on your website

Answer (score 0):

When ever you plan the ad system to your website, First you need to identify the effective placements and Banner size in each page.

Once that is done, You can implement the open source Ad manager like
[Advert tool](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/open-source-ad-campaigns-manager-advertool/)

Different Types of options you may get from the client as
1) They may give you the concept of ad, you may have to design the ad banner and place it
2) they may give the banner design according to the specs and you can place it

What ever the options, you will be having Iframe, so you can easily place the Html code and start showing and you can start making money out of it

Answer (score 0):

use opensource php advertising management system with stats and everything clients or end use needs

its called OpenX

```
sourceforge.net/projects/phpadsnew/
```